# Spring Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The full message is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryUserDetailsService' defined in file 
    [/Users/tdaley/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/wtpwebapps/cloud-management/WEB-INF/classes/
       org/cru/cloud/management/security/UserRepositoryUserDetailsService.class]: 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[org.cru.cloud.management.data.UserRepository]: : No qualifying bean of 
    type [org.cru.cloud.management.data.UserRepository] found for dependency: 
        expected at least 1 bean which qualifies 
        as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
     Dependency annotations: {}; 
nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
       No qualifying bean of type [org.cru.cloud.management.data.UserRepository] found 
       for dependency: expected at least 1 bean 
       which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
     Dependency annotations: {}
```

I'm using Java configuration.  The following code segments are from the spring boot tutorial gs-spring-security-3.2:

```
package org.cru.cloud.management.security;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.cru.cloud.management.data.User;
import org.cru.cloud.management.data.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserRepositoryUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user " + username);
        }
        return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
    }

    private final static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {    

        private UserRepositoryUserDetails(User user) {
            super(user);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return getEmail();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5639683223516504866L;
    }
}

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>
{
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This issue was resolved for me by moving my test class into a module that contains my Server.class

Answer (score 12):

Do you have the [@EnableJpaRepositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html) annotation somewhere in your config classes and is the scan set up correctly? By default the package in which the annotated class or interface exists becomes the base package for repository scan. You can control that by setting a value to the basePackages (or even better - basePackageClasses) property.

You could use Spring Tools Suite to check, what beans are declared in your context (Repositories should be visible under Spring Elements > Beans > Spring Data Repositories).

Comment: You nailed it. I had removed the "@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = MessageRepository.class)" from the DataConfiguration as I was stripping out the Message support that was in the sample. I replaced that with "@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)" and it now runs correctly (at least now I'm getting the login frame).

Comment: I'm a relative STS newbie, but I've used Eclipse for years. Where is Spring Elements found?

Comment: You have to add the Spring nature to the project (right click > Spring tools > Add spring nature). You may need to go to project properties and under Spring > Beans Support, on the config detection tab check the "Auto detection for annotated Java Spring configuration files". Once you did that and cleaned the project, Spring Elements should be visible as one of the elements under the project (like Deployment descriptor or Java Resources).

Comment: My Project already had a spring nature, but I had to check "Auto detection...". Also, if someone else is looking for it, it's called Spring Explorer not Spring Elements in my version. Thanks a BUNCH!!

Comment: Im using STS installed through the Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Luna. Its possible, that it's named differently in other versions:)

Answer (score 0):

[org.cru.cloud.management.data.UserRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type

Can not find UserRepository bean. Maybe you forgot to put annotation to UserRepository.

```
@Component
public MyClass implements UserRepository{}
```

if you autowire userRepository then you MyClass will be injected.

Also :

```
public MyClass implements UserRepository{}
public YourClass implements UserRepository{}

@Autowired
public blabla(@Qualifier("myClass") UserRepository userRepo)

@Autowired
public blabla(@Qualifier("yourClass") UserRepository userRepo)
```

I guess this will help.

Comment: I guess you don't have implementation of interface.

Answer (score 0):

Annotatate your class implementing `UserRepository` with spring `@Component` annotation

```
@Component
public MyUserRepository implements UserRepository
{
    User findByEmail(String email){
            return new User();
    }
}
```

Comment: As in the sample from which it was drawn, there is no implementing class. Just the UserRepository interface.

Comment: As far as i understand you want to inject a custom bean where you have written the business logic to actually get the user. So, where is this code implementated?

Comment: I think that if you get your annotations right, in my case "@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class", then Spring will build its own proxy for the interface.

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are using `@EnableJpaRepositories` to configure the database repository. It has two option load beans, the following one method you can use.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.test.repo"})
```

or

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=TestRepo.class)
```